# Input type text name in html tables

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

I have a code like this.

```
<form action="submit.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<th> Student </th>
<th> Subject </th>
<th> Grade </th>
</tr>
$sql = mysql_query("select * from tblsubjectgrade");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['subject'].'</td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="grade" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
echo '<input type="submit" />';
</form>
```

My problem is, if i have 20 students i will input a grade in each student and when i click the submit button all of the entered grade in each student must  save into the database named tblgrade. The names of each   must be different in each input. Anyone can help me?

Comment: `<input type="text" name="grade[]" />`, or `<input type="text" name="grade[' . $row['id'] . ']" />` - @davey has right syntax for supplied code

Comment: Actually `<input type="text" name="grade['.$row['id'].']" />`, or else you don't know which grade belongs to which student.

Comment: can you give the structure of tblgrade?

Comment: my tblgrade has id, name, subject, grade.

Answer (score 1):

`grade` should be an array, in your case it's just one value.

If your table structure has an ID, assign it to the name, like so

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo'<tr>';
echo '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>';
echo '<td>'.$row['subject'].'</td>';
echo '<td><input type="text" name="grade['.$row['id'].']" /></td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Then in PHP you will have a `$_POST["grade"]` array, containing all the values, associated with the actual table.

You can access them by `$_POST["grade"][row_id]`

Answer (score 0):

to update/insert them on database you can use this:

```
<?php 
foreach($_POST["grade"] as $id => $grade) { 
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tblgrade WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    $query = "UPDATE tblgrade SET grade = '$grade' WHERE id = '$id'";
    else
    $query = "INSERT INTO tblgrade SET id='$id', grade = '$grade'";
    mysql_query($query);
}
?>
```

if you need to save their name & subject if the id doesn't exists you'd have to put those in input fields as well.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
$rowCount = $_POST['hiddenName'];
for($i=1; i<=$rowCount; $i++)
{
  $_POST['name_'.$i]
}
```

or you can do something like this:

HTML markup:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="name[]" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject[]" ></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="grade[]"> </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

PHP markup:

```
<?php  
$rowCount =  count($_POST['name']); 
  echo "<table>";
  for($i=1; $i<=$rowCount; $i++)
  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>".$_POST['name'][$i -1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$_POST['subject'][$i -1]."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$_POST['grade'][$i -1]."</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
  echo "</table>";
?>
```